# Unable to deploy featuretools as EntitySet.read_pickle() method missing

Tags: python, featuretools

With reference to the deployment methods for **featuretools 'v0.7.0'** as mentioned on [deployment page](https://docs.featuretools.com/guides/deployment.html)

I have my **feature_defs** saved using `ft.save_features` method however upon successfully loading the defs using `ft.load_features` I found that the next dependency to calculate feature matrix viz. `ft.calculate_feature_matrix` is EntitySet!

I found there no way to persist `EntitySet`. As I could only find `EntitySet.to_pickle()` method but nothing to load from the pickle!

I have a new Dataframe that I would like to append my features on but without the parent Dataframes or the entity set its not possible.

Kindly advise if I missed anything.

```
Entityset: None
  Entities:
    branches [Rows: 82, Columns: 1]
    suppliers [Rows: 2953, Columns: 1]
    manufacturers [Rows: 11, Columns: 1]
    states [Rows: 22, Columns: 1]
    employees [Rows: 3270, Columns: 1]
    pincodes [Rows: 6698, Columns: 1]
    customers [Rows: 233154, Columns: 38]
  Relationships:
    customers.branch_id -> branches.branch_id
    customers.supplier_id -> suppliers.supplier_id
    customers.manufacturer_id -> manufacturers.manufacturer_id
    customers.state_id -> states.state_id
    customers.employee_code_id -> employees.employee_code_id
    customers.current_pincode_id -> pincodes.current_pincode_id
```

`ft.save_features(features_defs_branches, 'branches.ft`')

I have another customer's to calculate for, How do I do it?

viz.

```
new_predictions.py

df_new_customers = pd.read_csv('customers.csv')

features_loaded = ft.load_features('branches.ft')
feature_matrix = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features_loaded, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above, you need to create the same entityset out the new data in `df_new_customers`. Once you have the entityset of your new data, you can load the features and calculate them.

If you want to read a previously saved entity you can use `featuretools.read_entityset('path/to/entityset/')`. You can see all the serialization methods [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/api_reference.html#entityset-serialization). That being said, in this situation, I don't think you need to serialize and deserialize the entityset.

Comment: `featuretools.read_entityset('path/to/entityset/')` works. Thanks!